# How to trigger an ansible playbook on git update?

Tags: git, ansible

I am an UNIX admin and recently started working on Ansible to automate routine tasks.

Now I have a requirement that an Ansible playbook should automatically executes as soon as some one updates or make any changes to a particular git repo. I can not use third party tool.

And I did not get any details on how I can do it. Even GitHub Actions option is not enabled for us. Can someone help if this is really possible?

Comment: [`post-update` hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-update), perhaps.

Comment: git pull + run the playbook  from a cron ?

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. I got a solution, which I will put in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved through Ansible tower. Ansible tower has a template type of "Workflow Template" which can do this work. Although it require a little setup which is mentioned under Ansible Documentation below:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/workflow_templates.html

By the use of webhook it can easily be done. I have already tested it in my environment.